# Go Lang HTTP Connection Not Found

Tags: go

I'm a newbie to Go, writing a script to test whether my web-server's are up and mai if not. Everything's working except one niggling issue which is driving me crazy, tried quite a few solutions posted elsewhere.

The issue is when the web server is totally down and does not reply, Go is crashing:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x40140e]

goroutine 16 [running]:
runtime.panic(0x68b1c0, 0x83bfe2)
        c:/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:279 +0x11f
main.httpGET(0x6f0530, 0x15)
httpcheck.go
:57 +0x32e
main.main()
httpcheck.go
:43 +0x3b

goroutine 19 [finalizer wait]:
runtime.park(0x415bb0, 0x840c38, 0x83eda9)
        c:/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1369 +0xac
runtime.parkunlock(0x840c38, 0x83eda9)
        c:/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1385 +0x42
runfinq()
        c:/go/src/pkg/runtime/mgc0.c:2644 +0xdd
runtime.goexit()
        c:/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445
exit status 2
```

Here's what i have till the crash....

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go"
    "os"
    "time"
    "net"
)

var finishedWaiting bool
var timeout = time.Duration(2) * time.Second
var httpClient = http.DefaultClient

func main() {
    const url = "http://doesnotexist.com"
    httpGET(url)
    log.Println("main is running")

}

func httpGET(url string) {
    log.Println("httpGet is runnning")

    resp, err := httpClient.Get(url)

    if err != nil && !doesFileExist("down") {

    }

    if resp.StatusCode != 200 && !doesFileExist("down") {
        isDown()

    } else if resp.StatusCode == 200 && doesFileExist("down") {
        log.Println("200 response")
        sendmail("up")
        removeDownFile()

    }
}

func sendmail(status string) {
    sg := sendgrid.NewSendGridClient("user", "pass")
    message := sendgrid.NewMail()
    message.AddTo("admin@website.com")
    message.AddToName("WebBot")

    if status == "down" {
        message.SetSubject("Websites Down")
        message.SetText("Sites may be down")
    } else {
        message.SetSubject("Website Up")
        message.SetText("Sites are back Up")
    }
    message.SetFrom("admin@website.com")
    if r := sg.Send(message); r == nil {
        fmt.Println("Email sent!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}

//checks if the file name is present
func doesFileExist(name string) bool {
    if _, err := os.Stat(name); err != nil {
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

// write down file
func writeDownFile() {
    contents, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("")
    ioutil.WriteFile("down", contents, 0x777)

}

//remove down file if server is back up
func removeDownFile() {
    os.Remove("down")

}

func sleepForTen() {
    log.Println("sleeping for 10.....")
    time.Sleep(10000 * time.Millisecond)
    finishedWaiting = true
    main()

}

func isDown() {
    if finishedWaiting != true {
        sleepForTen()

    } else {
        writeDownFile()
        log.Println("200 response")
        sendmail("down")
    }
}
```

A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated, to help me gracefully determine if the connection cant be established at all.

Thanks.

Comment: that is not all the code ... where re the isDown function ... ?

Comment: Apart from adding isDown(), also copy what row the panic occurs on, please.

Comment: OK added what i have

Comment: Please: Handle *all* your errors, properly format your code (it hurts reading such Go code) and remove stray blank lines and don't try to be clever, e.g. do not call main again from somewhere (ugly even if doable).

Comment: Looks like your program is calling itself every 10 seconds for infinite number of times, if your server is down. You can try using a cron job which checks the server status just once or just x number of times.

Comment: Post the complete File. Should we guess line numbers?

Comment: Is that really the full stack-trace?

Comment: @jimb Yes that was the full stack trace. Answered below anyways.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're ignoring the `err` object. `resp` is probably nil because of this error, which causes a panic when you try to access `resp.StatusCode`. I'm not sure what's the point with `doesFileExist`, but try this :

```
func httpGET(url string) {
    log.Println("httpGet is runnning")

    resp, err := httpClient.Get(url)

    if err != nil || resp.StatusCode != 200 && !doesFileExist("down") {
        isDown()
    } else if resp.StatusCode == 200 && doesFileExist("down") {
        log.Println("200 response")
        sendmail("up")
        removeDownFile()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @sebcap26. My first Go code. Much appreciated to get a straight non-sarcastic answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to check `resp.StatusCode` even if the Get returned an error. The `http.Response` is not valid in this case, and may be nil, or contain nil pointers, so you cannot use it.

Answer (score -1):

If an error occurs in the `get` you just continue with the program. No wonder `resp` will be nil later.

That's ofc only a guess, since we can only guess the line numbers.